# Protobuf C# how to remove field?

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have fields serialized to binary file in protobuf. Now I want remove one field.

```
[ProtoMember(9, AsReference = true)]// to remove
 private MyClass obj; // to remove
```

and now I want to leave serialize this object, and remove from serialization, but I need to open old files. So I can't open this files. When I try open file I have exception:

```
Internal error; a key mismatch occurred
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this works/haven't tried it: Remove the property annotation and leave the number 'free' (as in no other property should have the number 9). When you get the exception about the key mismatch try this: Create a new scheme in/for the runtime model, add the type as is and then call `model[type].Add(9, "obj")` and try deserializing with that scheme. Serializing should obviously only be done with the `Default` scheme. Writing this as a comment because I don't know if this works. After you converted all files this way you can remove the property and the body of the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is probably to leave it where it is, and add:

```
private bool ShouldSerializeobj() => false;
```

this adds "conditional serialization" of the member `obj`, which means that it won't be serialized. It will, however, still be processed when deserializing.

Note: it is the `AsReference = true` that is making this more complex. Usually, you can simply remove the field.